# How to read a selected file to Bytes or into a Stream

Tags: react-native, file, webrtc, bytestream

I'm trying to send a file selected using **react-native-document-picker** over WebRTC, but I can't seem to get to reading it to bytes.

In a browser I would use a **FileReader** to read from`<input type="file">`.

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {

    var arrayBuffer = this.result,
      array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
      binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);

    console.log(binaryString);

  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);

}, false);
```

In **React Native** I select a file as follows :

```
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

const handleDocumentSelection = useCallback(async () => {
    const file = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        presentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
    });

    // Send file via WebRTC
}, []);
```

How would I go about reading a file to bytes in React Native?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Would [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) library work for you ?
We use ```RNFS.readFile(fileUri, "base64");``` to read bin files

Comment: Hi @sushrut619 It worked great. I'd tried it a number of times, but it just wasn't working. I did a copy-paste of your suggestion and it did! I would accept your answer if you'd it post it as an answer. Thank you for the reply. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to read a binary file in our react-native app.

Import it as
`const RNFS = require("react-native-fs");`
and then read file as
`const fileBin = await RNFS.readFile(otaFileUri, "base64");`

Furthermore, to convert it back into bytes(Uint8Array) we use [rfc4648](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfc4648)

Answer (score 1):

The library 'react-native-fs' has a function called read() which can read parts of a file.

```
read(filepath: string, length = 0, position = 0, encodingOrOptions?: any): Promise<string>
```

I used this function with a loop to read a whole file without putting the whole file in RAM (which is what most libraries do). My case was to upload large files (+1GB) with tus upload protocol.